# Captcha with Arithmetic Operation. Where to save the answer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am adding a simple arithmetic operation, eg. "2 + 4 = ", captcha to a MVC web site.

I generate random numbers and random operation and display the question in the view.

When the form is submited I need to know which numbers and operation was used to validate the answer.

Where should I "save" those values so I can validate it later?

1. In a Session variable?
2. In a Cookie?
3. In the ViewModel and place them in hidden inputs?

Could someone advise me on this?

Comment: In any case not in a way the client can read them, so skip 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cookie is meant for persisting data across sessions, that isn't compatible with the idea behind a captcha. What would even be the benefit of storing it in a cookie? The next login will be in a new session and will have a different arithmetic operation.
That is not to mention that you don't want this client side all together.

Storing it in the session should be just fine: usually a relog is expected when the session expires so it will automatically be removed as well.

Don't use hidden inputs. That would make it a little too easy for someone specifically targetting you.